# How can I skip a corrupt ZipEntry on inputstream

Tags: java, zip

When trying to extract a zip file using an inputstream a **java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry CRC (expected 0x... but got 0x...)** is thrown for an entry.

The following entries seem to be uncorrupted, when I check with unzip -t . Catching the 'crc' zip exception is not enough, because when I call zipInputstream.getNextEnty() another exception is thrown: **java.io.IOException: Push back buffer is full**. I tried to skip bytes to the next entry, but to no avail. Any suggestion appreciated.

```
    public void unzip() {
    try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(...)){
        ZipEntry entry;

        while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            try {
                byte[] b = IOUtils.toByteArray(zipInputStream);
                // do something useful
            } catch (ZipException e) {
                // read bytes for this entry
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is fixing the zip file with `zip -F` or `zip -FF` an option?

Comment: @VGR I only have handle on the inputstream.